# PHP string to Speech with Google Translate TTS stopped working MIME ERROR in all browsers

Tags: php, text-to-speech, translate

I have a php simple code : string to speech which uses "Google Translate TTS". But it stopped working MIME ERROR in all browsers a few days ago

First I notice some Errors in the console:

> could not be decoded, error: Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_METADATA_ERR (0x806e0006)

So, I've been trying to fix those, reboot, reinstall.

I though it was because of Soundflower ( which I just happened to install ). So, uninstalled it. And no success.

I deleted all the cookies, cleared all the historical data. I reinstalled the latest version. I test it on other Browsers: Firefox & Safari.

So, I went to the root of the problem, a very simple example:

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello+world

First, thing I notice, they added a CAPTCHA.
Once passed the Captcha in get an error. => I made sure again that I have the latest version of FF. But no success.

In Firefox and Safari: give a MIME ERROR

No video with supported format and MIME type found

In Google: Access to translate.google.com was denied. You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403

Are you getting the same thing? How can we fix it?

UPDATED: I also opened FF in safe mode and uncheck Hardware Acceleration under Performance.

Comment: did you by any chance exceed any quota's on a so-called `free$` google api ? read the small print if you are using one of them.

Comment: @ YvesLeBorg, Hello Yves, to my knowledge no. But when you click on the link above, does it work for you or do you also get a MIME error?
No video with supported format and MIME type found